# TIA PORTAL v11. Open existing project

Tags: virtual-machine, plc

I have to use an existing project in STEP7/TIA PORTAL v11 and I have the PLC (CPU 1212C AC/DC/RLY) with the code downloaded inside it which is connected to a touch panel (KTP600 Basic Color PN).

What I want is to download the code from the PLC to my computer to try to modify it, is this posible?

Because I've tried to connect it to my PC and it doesn't detect it. It turns on the ERROR and the MAINT leds in red.

The configuration is over a virtual machine (VMware player with Windows 7) because my PC has Windows 8 installed and it doesn't support TIA PORTAL is there any problem with this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If program was uploaded with TIA11 it is not good idea to use v13. What is more with other version you need new licence keys.
From your vm ping the plc address if itis in right subnet. Then serch for sccessible nodes. On your picture i see that you should try using 'search all accessible devices'.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to version 13 of TIA Portal. This version can run under Windows 8.

Under VMWare you have to change the network settings for your Virtual Machine to bridged. Also install VMWware Tools.

Comment: ok! but how can I change the network settings for your Virtual Machine to bridged?

Comment: In the machine settings. Stop the virtual machine, and then you can change the settings. See help of VMWware Player.

When this does noet work, pleas see if the PLC is viewable in the online devices tree in the project view.

Answer (score 0):

Those are some steps that I would try.

- make sure you can ping it from inside your Virtual Machine. It will validate the route to the plc (cable, network config). It’s not a necessary step to connect to a plc, but it’s a good check.
- Go to Control Panel on Windows, then PG/PC , then make sure that you have the right Hardware Interface Active
- If you still not able to see the PLC, I advise you to to download PRONETA, if it still doesn’t show up there, then the research would have to go deeper. Until today, I’ve only one time in all year when a device have not apeares in Proneta.